# C# mailing with BCC to PHP ready mail server using Custom Headers

Tags: c#, email

Got an issue about C# mailing.

According to [rfc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.6.3) format has no problem when BCC added to the custom header!

However according to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage.headers?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#System_Net_Mail_MailMessage_Headers) BCC info that is added to custom header will be deleted!

So in this particular situation I have to send an email trough C# code to a server that accepts BCC info in the custom header only...

How can I achive that? So far what I've tried is below;

```
// Mail Configurations
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.None;
mail.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
mail.HeadersEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
mail.BodyTransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.Base64;
mail.From = new MailAddress(FROM, FROM, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);   // From
mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(TO, TO, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8));      // EmailTo
// mail.CC.Add(new MailAddress(CC, CC, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8));      // CC
// mail.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(BCC, BCC, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8));   // BCC
mail.Headers.Add("BCC", BCC); // BCC 2nd method adding in headers as PHP does
mail.Subject = Subject;
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
mail.Body = "<div>Hello World!<div>";
mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(FileName));
// SMTP Configurations
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient(SMTP, PORT);
SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
SmtpServer.DeliveryFormat = SmtpDeliveryFormat.International;
SmtpServer.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
SmtpServer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(SMTPUser, SMTPPass);
// Send Mail
SmtpServer.Send(mail);
// Clear All
mail.To.Clear();
mail.Bcc.Clear();
mail.Headers.Clear();
mail.Attachments.Clear();
```

**Edit:** Depending on the comments I've also tried MailKit library.
It had no effect on BCC the code I've used is;

```
// Mail
var message = new MimeMessage();
message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, FROMName, FROM));
message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, TO, TO));
message.Cc.Add(new MailboxAddress(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, CC, CC));
message.Bcc.Add(new MailboxAddress(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, BCC, BCC));
message.Subject = Subject;
message.Priority = MessagePriority.Normal;
message.Importance = MessageImportance.Normal;
message.XPriority = XMessagePriority.Normal;
// With Body Builder 
var builder = new BodyBuilder();
builder.HtmlBody = "<div> Hello World! </div>"; // Set the html version of the message text
builder.Attachments.Add(FileName);              // We may also want to attach some files
message.Body = builder.ToMessageBody();         // Now we just need to set the message body and we're done
// SMTP connect
using (var client = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient())
{
    client.Connect(SMTP, SMTPPort, false);
    // Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication
    client.Authenticate(SMTPUser, SMTPPass);
    client.Send(message);
    client.Disconnect(true);
}
```

Comment: How is this related to PHP or PHPMailer?? I removed those tags for you. Don't spam completely irrelevant stuff in your question, please, it just wastes people's time clicking on things which they're not interested in :-).

Comment: The server is a PHP ready mailer system and uses PHP mailer normally.. Some PHP experts might have know some issues with it

Comment: You've said "PHP mail server"...are you saying you've written / deployed an SMTP server implemented using PHP? Can't say I've heard of that before, but ok, maybe it exists. Either way, the problem isn't any PHP code. PHPMailer is a library for **sending** mail **to** an SMTP server, it is not used to **receive** mails sent from another application (such as your C# app). It's a bit unclear but I think you may have misunderstood your application architecture somehow. Your C# code sends a mail to some SMTP server. How that's implemented, we cannot tell from the code you've shown.

Comment: The BCC is removed (in a normal SMTP server) because the person receiving the mail should not see the BCC info. A second mail is sent to the person given in the BCC.

Comment: @BerkerYüceer SMTP is SMTP, no matter what. It doesn't matter how it's implemented. On the other hand, the MSDN docs strongly advise *against* using the obsolete SmptClient, suggesting MailKit instead. Why are you trying to modify the headers instead of setting the `Bcc` property in the first place?

Comment: @ADyson I didn't mean "PHP mail server" PHP ready mail server sorry for the header edited now.. PHP mailer sends BCC info in the header as the server recieves BCC info in the header. I am simply and humbly ask advices how can I do the same in C#.

Comment: "PHP ready mail server" returns no useful results on Google. Is this some homemade system?

Comment: @Luuk why there is a second mail being sent? That makes no sense.. BCC's are hidden in the sent email what supposed to happen.

Comment: `how can I do the same in C#`...why don't you just use the BCC property of the message object, as per the documentation, and probably every example you'd ever see online? That MSDN link you provided says _" So any mail header in the headers collection that can be set using a property on the MailMessage class should only be set using the MailMessage class property or as a parameter passed when a MailMessage initializes a MailMessage object"_ . So use this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage.bcc?view=net-6.0

Comment: @ADyson The company provides this service tells me that their server is a "PHP ready mail server" I dont know how it happens but what they explained after is they receive BCC info in the header as PHP mailer does..

Comment: I think the company gave you a meaningless phrase (probaby invented by their marketing people, not the technical team). SMTP is a standard protocol, you can connect to it from any application. There's nothing special about PHP in that sense. The mailserver won't know what programming language was used to create the messages it receives.

Comment: @ADyson so how do you explain when a PHP mailer code sends BCC info with no fault but C# code fails to send BCC..

Comment: "If you add a recipient's name to the Bcc (blind carbon copy) box in an email message, a **copy** of the message is sent to the recipient that you specify. Any recipients added to the Bcc box will not be shown to any other recipients who receive the message."  (see: [BCC field](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/show-hide-and-view-the-bcc-blind-carbon-copy-field-04304e27-63a2-4276-8884-5077fba0e229))

Comment: `how do you explain when a PHP mailer code sends BCC info with no fault but C# code fails to send BCC`...the documentation link you gave already explains it - the C# library deliberately strips any custom BCC header you create **before** it sends the message. But it does that because, as I've just quoted to you, you're supposed to use the **specific BCC property** of the MailMessage object, not a custom header. The documentation already tells you everything you need to know about your problem, and gives you the solution.

Comment: `mail.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(BCC, BCC, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8));`...you already wrote the code, but you commented it out, I don't really understand why?

Comment: @ADyson If you properly check my code up there adding BCC to the header is done after I tried to add as a normal  "mail.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(BCC, BCC, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))" format both did not work and BCC address did not receive the email.

Comment: That is why I tried to add it to the header just like in PHP mailer but seems like this issue has nothing to do with code but the provider it self...

Comment: You can't conclude that adding the BCC "didn't work" unless you actually examine the raw message sent to the SMTP server, and examine the SMTP server's logs to see how it actually processed that message. I'd expect the message will have been delivered to the SMTP server containing the correct data, but feel free to test it yourself. Not receiving a message is **not** the same as it not being sent. A lot else can go wrong in between. It could easily be the mailserver's fault, not yours. But be in no doubt that the `BCC` property **is** the way to add a BCC to a MailMessage object.

Comment: However, as someone pointed out earlier, the whole SmtpClient, MailMessage etc class library is deprecated by Microsoft and you shouldn't be writing any new code with it. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-6.0) says _"Important:
We don't recommend that you use the SmtpClient class for new development because SmtpClient doesn't support many modern protocols. Use MailKit or other libraries instead. For more information, see SmtpClient shouldn't be used on GitHub."_

Comment: So I don't know where you learned about it, but the resource was probably out of date. So to minimise the chances of problems I'd strongly recommend switching to MailKit instead in your C# code. You never know, it might even magically fix this problem (although BCC is such a basic fundamental bit of the protocol, that I'd be surprised if SmtpClient had got it wrong.)

Comment: @ADyson I am not an expert on mailing and this was the garbage that was used in an old system that I am trying to update so MailKit I will go for now. If you also can send this as an answer I can easily accept cause using an out of date library makes no sense... Thank you kind sir!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos and also you for focusing us on MailKit!

Comment: @ADyson Quick upadate on the issue. I have implemented MailKit to the project. Same issue continues. So it doesn't matter which library I am using this is certainly all about SMTP server it self... Even with MailKit BCC does not work.

Comment: Agree. You should speak to the provider of the server and collaborate with them.

Comment: Another test you could do is simply connect to the mailserver using a regular graphical Email client such as Outlook or Thunderbird, and try sending mail via that and see what happens. That would 100% rule out issues with your code.

Comment: I still updated the question those who may appear here might wanna know what might cause this issue..

Comment: When you are updating the question, can you also provide more details about the (smtp)server used (Like: brand/version) ?

Comment: @Luuk sadly I do not have that information.

Comment: Just stop. BCC addresses should never appear in headers. It completely undermines the point of having them BCC. BCC is used at the SMTP level to add additional recipients without them appearing in the message itself. To see this working, you should show the SMTP transcript, and I doubt very much that Microsoft doesn't support BCC.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I'm following along correctly, but it sounds like you need to send a message where the raw `Bcc:` header is sent in the headers to the SMTP server?

This is highly non-standard and very suspect since the whole point of the `Bcc:` header is that it gets stripped at send time because recipients in the `Bcc:` header field are meant to be *BLIND* Carbon Copy recipients (aka, hidden to everyone who receives the message).

That said... if you REALLY REALLY do need to include the `Bcc:` header in the message data that gets uploaded to the SMTP server, then you can do this:

```
var options = FormatOptions.Default.Clone ();
options.HiddenHeaders.Add (HeaderId.ContentLength);
options.HiddenHeaders.Remove (HeaderId.ResentBcc);
options.HiddenHeaders.Remove (HeaderId.Bcc);
options.NewLineFormat = NewLineFormat.Dos;

client.Send (options, message);
```

Note: Currently the Resent-Bcc and Bcc headers are not hidden in the default FormatOptions, I just added those .Remove() calls to illustrate how to control which headers get hidden vs not.

The SmtpClient.Send() methods that do not take a FormatOptions argument use an internal FormatOptions that add the Bcc, Resent-Bcc, and Content-Length headers to the hidden list.